# Remove shutdown/reboot options from logout window

Tags: centos, kde, logout

In my CentOS5 installation in KDE, users get presented the options to terminate the session, reboot, and shutdown. Since this computer should always remain on, I'd like to remove the reboot and shutdown option from the menu to avoid an accidential reboot. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You do this with the `AllowShutdown none` setting in the system kdmrc file, which can be found in `/usr/share/config/kdm/`.

See http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kdm/kdm-files.html for more details.

Comment: I've replaced the two instances of "AllowShutdown" to "none", but when I select "Logout..." from the start-menu (or whatever KDE calls it), I still get all the option as user.